# How to display map key value pair on visualforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to display map key and value in pageblocktable.I am doing this by

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!MapOfFieldDataTrack}" var="item"  >
                    <apex:column value="{!objects}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!item}"/>
                    <apex:column>
                        <apex:repeat value="{!MapOfFieldDataTrack[item]}" var="updateRec">
                            {!updateRec} <br/>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </apex:column>

          </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

But I want to show in following format:

```
key1 value1
key1 value2
key1 value3
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

First create the key list in controller as below and repeat it in VF page with the key values of the map in your controller:

```
Set<String> keyValues = yourMap.keySet();
```

visualforce code:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!keyValues }" var="key">
    <apex:column headerValue="{!key}"/> <!-- key --->
    <apex:column value="{!yourMap[key]}"/> <!-- Value--->
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Saroj, I tried as you told. but it is not working as per my requirement. My requirement is : key should repeat for every value of map and it should be as separate row of table. like: if there is map<key,list<values>> then my pageblocktable should display 
key value1 key value2 as separate row

Comment: @Saroj Bera : you are getting keyset into list this will return error. keyset is gettting unique values so we need set instead of list. correct me if i'm wrong
Set<String> keyValues = yourMap.keySet();

Answer (score 2):

Then you need to modify your code as

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!MapOfFieldDataTrack}" var="item"  >
    <apex:column value="{!item}"/>  <!-- key --->
    <apex:column value="{!MapOfFieldDataTrack[item]}"/>  <!-- Value--->
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this scenario for my own purpose as shown below:--

Controller:--

```
public class MapLoad_test {
    public Map<ID, Account> myMap {
        get {
            Map<ID, Account> m = new Map<ID, Account>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 20]);
            return m;
        }
    }
}
```

VF Page:--

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Account List" id="accounts_list">

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myMap}" var="acctId"  >
        <apex:column value="{!myMap[acctId].Id}"/>  <!-- key --->
        <apex:column value="{!myMap[acctId].Name}"/>  <!-- Value--->
    </apex:pageBlockTable>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

Let me know if it helps..

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

<apex:repeat value="{!YOURMAP NAME}" var="MYVARIABLE">


  **{!MYVARIABLE}**


</apex:repeat>

Comment: I have dobuts that this would work. Have you tested this approach yourself?